# How to count leading zeros?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to make a Regex to count leading zeros on the following formats: 
`01`, `001` and `0001`.

These are some id's that I need to process somehow.

I tried something like this:

```
id.split(/^0{1,3}/)
```

For example, if my input is `0001`, I would like to see something like this:

```
['0', '0', '0']
```

But I'm getting this:

```
["", "1"]
```

I only care about the leading zeros, and I can't count the ones that are after the format I specified.

Comment: why are you using split?

Comment: Use `.match` rather than `.split`.

Comment: Why not *test*? `/^0{1,3}/.test(string)`.

Comment: @epascarello because I could count the 0's and say like, this id is a level 2 id because it has 1 zero... this id is a level 3 id because it has 2 zeros...

I'm going to try to use match.

Comment: Are you using the `^` symbol to mean NOT? Right now it's meaning 'beginning of input'. I'm just trying to clarify what you want.

Comment: "validate", "filter", "split", "see", "count". What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: `"0001".match(/(^0+)/)[0].length`

Comment: [This might help.](https://regex101.com/r/TifcNR/1)

Comment: @MaclainAnderson I think you need to look what ^ can be in reg exp.

Comment: @epascarello I just did what you said here but a little bit different and it seems to work.

Thank you all!

Comment: @epascarello I'm not super well-versed, but as far as I know, outside of square brackets, it marks the beginning of input, whereas inside square brackets it means 'not these explicit characters'

Comment: @MaclainAnderson: Quite. Inside square brackets *at the very beginning* it means **not** (as in `[^e]` - not an e).

Comment: @Jan Thanks for the confirmation. I think @danibrum was trying to use 'NOT 0' as a delimiter, in order to count the number of zeroes, in which case what he would want is `/[^0]{1,3}/`. But it looks like it got solved anyway. @epascarello has the more elegant answer than what I was going for.

Comment: `.match(/^0*/)[0].length` - no need for error checking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use match so you can get the zeros. With that, you can read the length. If there is no match, it returns null.

```
var str = "0001"
var match = str.match(/^0+/)
var level = match ? match[0].length : 0
```

in one line

```
var str = "0001"
var level = (str.match(/^0+/) || [''])[0].length
```

Answer (score 2):

You could have it all without any regular expression:

```js
let somenumber = "0001";

function count_leading_zeros(some_input) {
    let splitted = some_input.split("");
    let i = 0;
    while (splitted.shift() == 0) {
        i += 1;
    }
    return i;
}

console.log(count_leading_zeros(somenumber));
```

Answer (score 1):

`String#split` breaks strings into parts where regex matches the string part. Thus, the results you get are expected, `001` when split with `/^0{1,3}/` (the first 1, 2 or 3 zeros) will yield an empty string (at the start of string) and `1`.

You want to use a regex that always matches any number of zeros at the start of the string:

```js
console.log('001'.match(/^0*/)[0].length); // => 2
console.log('01'.match(/^0*/)[0].length);  // => 1
console.log('1'.match(/^0*/)[0].length);   // => 0
```

No need to use `||` or any kind of safeguarding here since `/^0*/` always matches, any amount of zeros (`0*`) at the start of the string (`^`).

Answer (score 0):

With lodash:

```
_.takeWhile(str, (c) => c === '0').length
```